# PyRevit / RevitPythonShell Custom Tools - How to disable Alt-Click "View Code" functionality?

Tags: revit-api, revit, revitpythonshell, pyrevit

I've begun developing some tools for my firm using RPS and thus would like to know how to disable the alt-click "view code" functionality as shown in PyRevit. I've gone through the documentation and scoured the web but I haven't seen any kind of solution provided. Has anyone come across anything?

Any tips or tricks/workarounds are appreciated.

Comment: There is no option to disable the Alt+Click functionality unless you are willing to create a custom pyRevit core for your firm. Here is where the check happens: https://github.com/eirannejad/pyRevit/blob/6f2cb14947c380c0713bef76e76aaeaa108d31e0/pyrevitlib/pyrevit/loader/basetypes/baseclasses.cs#L90

Comment: @EhsanIrannejad if you could post this as an answer instead of a comment, I'd be happy to check it as the answer. 

Also, could you please explain the logic behind making custom tools "alt-clickable" instead of making it an option? just curious. I'm a huge fan btw.

Comment: The pyRevit tools are all live scripts. So every time you click on a button, the linked script gets executed. The Alt+Click combination gives the user very quick access to the script source to make adjustments and changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option to disable the Alt+Click functionality unless you are willing to create a custom pyRevit core for your use only. [Here is where the check happens](https://github.com/eirannejad/pyRevit/blob/6f2cb14947c380c0713bef76e76aaeaa108d31e0/pyrevitlib/pyrevit/loader/basetypes/baseclasses.cs#L90)